# How to compute $\int\frac1x\Bigl(\sum\limits_{n\ge0}\frac{x^{2n}}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}\Bigr)^{-2}\mathrm dx$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

The background of $$\int\frac{1}{x}\left(\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{2n}}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}\right)^{-2}\text dx$$
is that it yields a second solution to $xy''+y-xy=0$ if you multiply it by the series in the integrand (first solution). My professor found an aproximate answer by multiplying the two series up to $5$th term and then he did long division with $1$ as numerator and the series squared as denominator. Nonetheless, what I was looking for is an exact solution.

I thought about this:
$$\frac{1}{\left(\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{2n}}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}\right)^2}=\sum_{k\geq 0}b_n x^k\implies 1=\left(\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{2n}}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}\right)^2\left(\sum_{k\geq 0}b_n x^k\right),$$
where
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left(\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{2n}}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}\right)^2 &=\left(\sum_{i\geq 0}\frac{x^{2i}}{2^{2i}(i!)^2}\right)\left(\sum_{j\geq 0}\frac{x^{2j}}{2^{2j}(j!)^2}\right)\\
&=\sum_{i\geq 0}\sum_{j\geq 0}\frac{x^{2(i+j)}}{2^{2(i+j)}(i!j!)^2}\\
&\overset{n=i+j}{=}\sum_{n\geq 0}\sum_{i= 0}^n\frac{x^{2n}}{2^{2n}(i!(n-i)!)^2}\\
&=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_nx^{2n},
\end{aligned}
$$
and thus,
$$
\left(\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n x^{2n}\right)\left(\sum_{k\geq 0}b_k x^k\right)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\sum_{k\geq 0}a_nb_kx^{2n+k}=\sum_{m\geq 0}\sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor m/2\rfloor}a_nb_{m-2n}x^m
$$
Finally, equating cofficients we find all $b_k$ and hence the antiderivative is simply
$$\int\frac{1}{x}\sum_{k\geq 0}b_kx^k\text dx=\int\left(\frac{b_0}{x}+\sum_{k\geq 0}b_{k+1}x^k\right)\text dx=b_0\ln x +\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{b_{k+1}}{k+1}x^{k+1}+C$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For exact solution.
Note that we have a Bessel function
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{2^{2n}(n!)^2} = I_0(x) .
$$
The integral is in integral tables as
$$
\int\frac{dx}{xI_0(x)^2} = -\frac{K_0(x)}{I_0(x)} .
$$
The first few terms of this series are:
$$
\ln x +(\gamma - \ln 2) - \frac{1}{4} x^2 + \frac{5}{128} x^4 + \dots
$$

Comment: Thank you, what's the series for the other Bessel function $Y_0$?

Comment: See here for $K_\nu$ `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_Iα,_Kα`